# Routing issue with express.js and nodemailer

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

Hi I am attempting to use nodemailer with gmail to create a contact form on my website however, I believe there is a routing issue that is causing the mail to be sent but I cannot mange to fix it.

My about.html page contains the code form below:

```
  <form id="contact" action="/contact" id="contact-form" method="post" role="form">
    <h3>Contact Form</h3>
    <fieldset>
      <input placeholder="Your name" type="text" tabindex="1" id="name" name="name" required autofocus>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <input placeholder="Subject" type="text" tabindex="1" id="subject" name="subject" required>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <input placeholder="Your Email Address" type="email" tabindex="2" id="email"  name="email" required>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <textarea placeholder="Type your message here...." tabindex="5" id="message" name="message"  required></textarea>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <button name="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit" data-submit="...Sending">Submit</button>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
```

And my app.js file that is the node server contains the code

```
//safe enviroment variables
require('dotenv').config();
//express routing
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();
var path =  __dirname + '/views/';
app.use(express.static('public'));
router.use(function (req,res,next) {
  console.log("/" + req.method);
  next();
});
router.get("/",function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(path + "index.html");
});
router.get("/about",function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(path + "about.html");
});
app.use("/",router);
app.use("*",function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(path + "404.html");
});
app.listen(8080, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 8080!')
})                    
//nodemail
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))

//collecting gmail username and password
const GMAIL_USER = process.env.GMAIL_USER
const GMAIL_PASS = process.env.GMAIL_PASS


// POST route from contact form
app.post("/contact", (req, res) => {
  async function main() {

  // Instantiate the SMTP server
  const smtpTrans = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'Gmail',
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
      user: GMAIL_USER,
      pass: GMAIL_PASS 
    }
  })

  
  // Specify what the email will look like
  const mailOpts = {
    from: GMAIL_USER , // This is ignored by Gmail
    to: GMAIL_USER,
    subject: `${req.body.subject}`,
    text: `${req.body.name} (${req.body.email}) says: ${req.body.message}`
  }


  // Attempt to send the email
  smtpTrans.sendMail(mailOpts, (error, response) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log('error email')
      res.sendFile(path + "index.html"); // Show a page indicating failure
    }
    else {
      console.log('email sent')
      res.sendFile(path + "about.html"); // Show a page indicating success
    }
  })
}

})
```

However when clicking the submit button the form it send me to the 404 page indicating that the form cannot find the post function since if it could then it would not redirect me to the post function. I have also added echos into the function to print to console if it is called which does not happen. I have tried changing the routing but can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: You need to move `app.listen()` to the end, below all your routes.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I tried that but it did not resolve the issue

Comment: You also need to move the `app.use("*", ...)` route down, or it will catch `/contact`